# Installing elixir with homebrew fails due to jpeg

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install elixir and it fails installing one of its dependencies, jpeg:

```
$ brew install elixir
==> Installing dependencies for elixir: jpeg, libtiff, wxmac, erlang
Error: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/jpeg is not a valid keg
```

So of course I try `brew install jpeg` and a few others:

```
$ brew install jpeg
Error: jpeg-jpeg already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink jpeg'
$ brew unlink jpeg
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg
$ brew info jpeg
jpeg: stable 8d (bottled)
JPEG image manipulation library
http://www.ijg.org
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/jpeg.rb
==> Options
--universal
Build a universal binary
```

And if I run `brew doctor`, it just tells me to install `jpeg`. Has anyone run into this before? I'm on Yosemite 10.10.5. I didn't expect to see `jpeg-jpeg already installed` after trying to install `jpeg`.

My `brew --config`:

```
$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: 070b76df5a4096dcc6196fc51e56185ae7dfd617
Last commit: 80 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
OS X: 10.10.5-x86_64
Xcode: 7.1
CLT: 7.1.0.0.1.1444952191
Clang: 7.0 build 700
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /Users/Me/.rbenv/shims/ruby => /Users/Me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_51, 1.6.0_65-b14-468
```

Updated with `brew remove --force jpeg`:

```
$ brew remove --force jpeg
$ brew install jpeg
Error: jpeg-jpeg already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink jpeg'
```

Comment: What happens with `brew remove --force jpeg` then reinstalling it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell just updated my question with that, but essentially I get the same `jpeg-jpeg already installed` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by following guidance in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/37250. Specifically, [this comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/37250#issuecomment-76468818). Following that, I just removed the directory at `/usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/jpeg` and was then able to install `jpeg` just fine.